# Cannot run scripting in visual studio code terminal(python)

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

[image: Errors]

Wondering what is the reason why I can't run the basic python in the visual studio code terminal. Did I have to install anything?

Comment: That's a Powershell terminal, not a Python terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Python extension, here you can know how to do it: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python